# Unexpected behavior of Python's variable scope

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

I'm a bit confused as to how Python's variable scope system works. Say I have situation like this:

```
a = 10
def test():
    print(a)
```

Then everything works just as I expect. Python first looks for a local variable `a`, fails to find it and then searches for a global variable.

However, in a situation like this:

```
a = 10
def test():
    print(a)
    a += 1
    print(a)
```

Python throws an UnboundLocalError exception, apparently originating from line 3 (`print(a)`). To me it seems that at least to this line nothing has changed, and I don't understand why there is an exception anyway.

Comment: Please search properly before posting

Comment: @therealprashant said the one who answered this.

Comment: @vaultah well sometimes do meet some stubborn people who need's to be answered :)

Comment: @therealprashant they're answered in the dupe, which is *the whole point* of identifying it as such. If you have a better answer, *write it there* so all the dupes pointing to it benefit. If not, sit on your hands.

Comment: @jonrsharpe got that. Thanks for the feedback. I will make sure that doesn't happens later

Answer (score 0):

Since python does not have variable declarations, every variable assignment inside the scope of a function is considered local. So, you always have to specify that that variable is a global one:

```
a = 10
def test():
    global a
    print(a)
    a += 1
    print(a)
test()
```

Comment: Recommending the use of `global` is a bad idea.